# How to translate "the Force" from Star Wars?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, contemporary-latin, word-request, technology, mythology

In Star Wars movies — and other media — there is an important concept called [the Force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Force_(Star_Wars)).
It is a magical energy field surrounding everything and giving special abilities for those who master its use.
(I assume many already know what it is, and I hope this description is adequate for the purposes of this question.)

**What would be a good Latin translation of "the Force" and why?**
The [Vicipaedia article on the movie series](https://la.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars) uses *Numen*, but the article does not look like high quality Latin.
Is *Numen* good, or would *Vis* or something else be better?
I am not aware of any Star Wars material in Latin, be it movie subtitles, comics or anything else.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Numen* isn't the best without either ignoring the "all around us" aspect or resorting to some discredited twentieth century arguments about the word. Still, as a means of personal power in a Jedi, I can see it being used.

However, what is most commonly used is indeed *vis*, which was standard at least back in 2000. For the full phrase, *Vis vobiscum* (or in the singular *Vis tecum*) has plenty of Google hits, some with and some without *sit*. (The *sit* here is poor Latinitas based on a literal translation of the English.)

Some places where it's found:

- [Soma's Dictionary of Latin Quotations, Maxims, and Phrases](https://books.google.com/books?id=BIxyWH0FKgYC&pg=PT565&lpg=PT565&dq=%22vis+tecum%22+star+wars&source=bl&ots=pJAJz-R_s5&sig=IEBHQ60mt8uJ70lWawE54p3OMzo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjUsdr9yrzQAhVSzWMKHXobA0o4ChDoAQgrMAY#v=onepage&q=%22vis%20tecum%22%20star%20wars&f=false)
- [Latin Discussion](http://latindiscussion.com/forum/latin/may-the-force-be-with-you.20937/) (see especially post #11)
- [Jon Stewart rally](http://boards.straightdope.com/sdmb/showthread.php?t=584119)
- [Some crazy Scientologist site](https://everythingisdianetics.wordpress.com/2016/01/03/vis-vobiscum-in-aeternam/)
- [Crap Tumblr posts](http://interretialia.tumblr.com/post/25024177906/sit-vis-tecum-may-the-force-be-with-you-from)
- [An SVR discussion](http://www.societasviaromana.net/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?p=9301&sid=bfcc23ae4a2e6b14c3afb43502855ec0#p9301)

Meanwhile, phrases with *numen tecum/numen vobiscum* are much, much less frequently used.

---

As a side note, there is no "right way" of translating it, since even in English "The Force" wouldn't have made sense in 1977. It's a fictional term that deliberately repurposes a common word for a new, specific sense. On that note, *vis* or *numen* could work, but we should default to what is commonly used, and that is the former.

Comment: Thank you, this is a nice answer! Perhaps *numen* is indeed a useful word in relation to the Force, but not a good translation of the word itself. *Numen cuiusque Jedi de Vi fluit* or something.

Comment: I think you should opt to remove the "crap" posts altogether: "vis vobiscum in aeternam" is just manifestly wrong, and if anything it just weakens your case.

Comment: @brianpck The crap posts are merely there to show its ubiquity.  Feel free to edit in better ones if you know of them.

Comment: The crap posts indeed show that *Vis* is ubiquitous, and that is one reason to favor it as a translation. I agree with @brianpck that there is some bad Latin behind some links, and that makes me think that perhaps not much thought went into choosing *Vis*. (Google Translate?) If there is no official Star Wars material in Latin, there is not going to be a canonical answer to my question. As most answers on the site, this one has room for improvement, but I still find it very valuable.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta As far as I know, there were no official translations of the books or movies or anything to Latin. It also was not Google translated, since I remember the phrase back when Google was just getting out of beta, and [this Usenet thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rec.arts.sf.starwars.misc/_pNUgengcCU) from 1998 had one person say they've been doing it a certain way for years.

Comment: @cmw Another good point: *vis* is the word that Newton used for "force" (physics)