# How to work around the missing cases of vis?

Tags: vocabulary, syntax, genitive, dative

The word *vis* does not have singular genitive and dative forms.
This makes it difficult to use *vis*.
(I was reminded of this difficulty by [this Star Wars question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/2040/79).)

Can you suggest methods of working around the missing forms of *vis* when writing Latin?
What should I do when syntax seems to require genitive or dative?
The easiest way would be to use a substitute word for these cases or to coin new forms for *vis*, but both feel like a disservice to legibility and style.
I am open to any suggestions.

For concrete examples, you can consider replacing *robur* with *vis* in the following sentences:

1. *Terror roboris magnus erat apud senatores.*
2. *Haud multum roboris remanet.*
3. *Vir quidam roboris nuclearis peritus acroasem praeparaverat.*
4. *Marcum miseret roboris mei.*
5. *Roboris Marci causa abire constitui.*
6. *Haec potio magica robori meo prodest.*
7. *Caesar non pietati sed robori vivebat.*
8. *Voluntas robori dissimilis est.*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Singular genitive and dative forms of *vis* exist but are very rare, according to the Gaffiot, which provides some examples:

[image: vis in Gaffiot]

Or in Calonghi:

[image]

[image]

So it may be possible to use those forms when needed (*vis* and *vi*).

Comment: Thanks! (+1) It's good to know that the forms exist. I wonder if they are safe to use in the sense that readers would actually understand.

Comment: Interesting how L/S and Gaffiot have exactly the same citations, quoted in exactly the same order (though with different sigla). These old dictionaries are obviously all copied from each other.

Comment: @fdb Is this not more a consequence of the rarity of the singular genitive and dative forms of *vis*?

Comment: I'm having one of those senior moments. What do you call a non-existent word put in a dictionary on purpose to track possible copyright infringement?

Comment: Both Gaffiot and Calonghi refer to the words   . . . 'animum advertit,equitibus suis hostium vi oppositis sarcinas legionarios in acervum iubet comportare . . .  '   — 'opposed by the force of the enemy' (b. afr. 69, period 2). Surely not dative, but ablative?

Comment: @AlexB.: Wikipedia just calls it a [fictitious entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fictitious_entry).

Comment: @AlexB. I've heard it called a Mountweazel.

Answer (score 4):

To find the singular forms of *vis* is, I believe, fairly rare though perfectly valid. The more prevalent way of 'working round' is to use the plural, usually interpreted as 'strength', etc., though in either a physical or moral sense. The plural is found in all cases — except, of course, the vocative — and any good dictionary will give examples.

You might consider alternatives such as *potestas* and *potentia*, though care is needed to ensure that either is exactly apposite to the case in hand, rather as English speakers must choose precisely between *puissance* and *pouvoir* in French.

I wonder where you found your concrete examples using [*robur*], some of which have unusual syntax; are they, perhaps, your own constructions?

Comment: Thanks! The examples are indeed my own constructions. I used *robur* merely as a placeholder for *vis* to make the sentences clear. I tried to go through uses of genitive and dative that are hard to express with other cases.

Answer (score 1):

I realize that Sir Isaac Newton's *Principia* (v. Reference [1](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/28233/28233-pdf.pdf)) is not part of the classical corpus, but he does talk quite a bit about *vis* in it, and he gives the word its modern definition.

From what I infer from reading the reference, he uses *vis* for the nominative and genitive, *vi* for the dative and ablative, and *vim* for the accusative.

Take a look and see whether you agree!