# Why do translators translate Newton's 2nd law as though it referred to "force" when it does not mention force?

Tags: translation-check, science, esse

Here's ***Newton's 2nd law***.

> Lex II: Mutationem motus proportionalem esse vi motrici impressae, et
> fieri secundum lineam rectam qua vis illa imprimitur.

The term *esse vi motrici* is often translated as *motor force*,
but we actually have related words: *essive* meaning *being alive* and *motrix* meaning *a cause of something*.

In addition, *Leonardo da Vinci* uses the word *forza* ,
which (I think) can be compared to *sforzàre* meaning *to strain, to overexert*.

Here is *Leonardo da Vinci’s* definition:

**Force as cause and effect**

> La forza è causa del moto, el moto è causa della forza

*The force is the cause of the motion; the motion is the cause of force.*

Tbh, my latin is almost non-existent, so if anyone answers this, please explain step by step.

Comment: My comments on this Quora post relate to this: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-proof-of-f-dp-dt

Comment: The Latin word *vis* means force and *vi* is the ablative form of *vis*.

Comment: “*essive* meaning *being alive*” ← in what language? Certainly not Latin …

Comment: The "vi" can also mean "vigor" as with the well known phrase "vim and vigor",  and "esse" means "to be". Motrici is often said to be related to "motrix" which is the female case of "an instigator" (eg. "flexion": "bending") - a mover is an instigator and "-i" indicates a plural, so it's "movers". Also, "mutationem" could mean "muta" ("mute") + "-tion"= "mute action" which to me implies a decay of motion, i.e "damping", so maybe it's really:                         
               Damping of motion is proportional to the vigor of movers impressed.

Comment: "vi" might be from a root word "ve-" ("out of-") https://www.wordsense.eu/vemens/#Latin https://www.wordsense.eu/vehemens/ https://www.wordsense.eu/vehement/

Comment: "Damping of motion is proportional to the alternation of movers impressed." - using "vicis" instead of "vigor". https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vicis#Latin

Answer (score 9):

As you mention, the phrase corresponding to "force" here is *vī mōtrici*, the ablative of *vīs mōtrix*. *Vīs* is a fairly standard word for "power" or "strength", while *mōtrix* is a feminine form of *mōtor* ("that which moves [something]"), which comes from *mōveō* "to move". The pair is usually translated into English as "motive force": literally, "the power that moves something".

*Forza* isn't a Latin word; Leonardo is writing in Italian, not Latin. *Forza* goes back to Latin *fortis* "strong", a separate word.

Comment: [Related](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/2040/how-to-translate-the-force-from-star-wars/2043#2043). (And a good reminder to fix that post.)

Comment: It should be noted that the word *motrix* was used before by Newtown - for example by Kepler. Specifically, it was not *vi motrix* but *anima motrix* a "soul" that resides in the plants or even vacant point. It was necessary to have an *anima motrix* in the absent of the solid orbs. Kepler later also used specifically the term *vis motrix*, brilliantly realizing that it must originate from the Sun (*fons virtutis motricis ex jam demonstratis in Solem competet*).  Having said that, I don't make the claim that Newton's *vis motrix* comes directly (or even indirectly)  from Kepler's *vis motrix*.

Comment: @d_e Very interesting, I didn't know _vis motrix_ existed prior to Newton! Even if the usage is different that's cool to know. Removed the sentence attributing it only to Newton.

Comment: [Also related](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/17115) (as the OP seems to have been confused by *esse*).